# POST request from Postman fails model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, postman

Inside my ASP.NET WebApi program, I have an `Author` model:

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I also have an `AuthorsController`, with a `PostAuthor(Author author)` method:

```
// POST: api/Authors
[ResponseType(typeof(Author))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAuthor(Author author)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // etc.
}
```

When I send a `POST` request programmatically inside my unit tests, `HTTP Status Code 201 Created` is returned:

[image]

However, when I send a `POST` request using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/), I receive `HTTP Status Code 400 Bad Request` instead:

[image]

As you can see, when I send a `POST` request using `Postman`, the argument passed into the `PostAuthor(Author author)` method is `null`, and model validation fails as a result:

[image]

What should I do to ensure that `POST` requests from `Postman` can be processed?

Comment: The error is not pretty obvious ? You are not in Visual Studio when you declare a JsonObject like this ` new { key = value } ` but you are in Postman where a JsonObject is created like `{ key : value , key1 : value1 } ` . Hope this helps

Comment: @my_g what is the value of author when you send your request programmaticly ?

Comment: if you send your author null and you put Name of author required automaticly your model is not valid this is why ModelState.IsValid is false and return badrequest

Comment: @GabrielCostin You're right; my sleep-deprived brain had missed the obvious solution...

Comment: @MY_G No problem , it can and it happens to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of changes: define it as `HttpPost` and use `FromBody` like

```
// POST: api/Authors
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Author))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAuthor([FromBody] Author author)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace = with : in postman body, its a JSON after all.

Comment: You're right; my sleep-deprived brain had missed the obvious solution...

Comment: It happens to all of us. Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

If you send in application/json and your API wait as INBOUND JSON, so try to send in JSON format, something like

```
{
"Id":"6",
"Name":"P.G. Wodehouse"
}
```